# load image using cv2.imread

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, opencv

When I was trying to load a image from path using `cv2.imread`, it shows 'none'. 
I created the UI to upload the image using flask.

Here's what I've done:

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'])

app = Flask(__name__)
#app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/')
def uploadfile():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/uploader', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    target = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, 'static/')
    upload = os.path.join(target, 'uploads/')
    if not os.path.isdir(target):
        os.mkdir(target)
        os.mkdir(upload)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(upload, filename))

    image=cv2.imread('/home/user/image/static/uploads/filename')
    print("image",image)
```

My image isn't loaded to the 'image'. The result of print is

`image,None ,`

Comment: The filename at the end of `cv2.imread()` is not expanded. You need to append the variable to the path.

Comment: /home/user/image/static/uploads/{{filename}} i did this too

Comment: yes............

Comment: i replaced the path with another image path in my local disk it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my path wasn't correct

```
image=cv2.imread(os.path.join(upload,filename))
```

above solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

About 95% of the `NoneType` errors from `cv2.imread` come from having an invalid file path
([OpenCV: Resolving NoneType errors](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/26/opencv-resolving-nonetype-errors/)). That is, the path spec is wrong or missing something, or the filename is incomplete - possibly missing the extension (*png*, *jpg*, etc.)

The [current list of supported image file types](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) includes:

- Windows bitmaps - *.bmp, *.dib
- JPEG files - *.jpeg, *.jpg, *.jpe
- JPEG 2000 files - *.jp2
- Portable Network Graphics - *.png
- WebP - *.webp
- Portable image format - *.pbm, *.pgm, *.ppm *.pxm, *.pnm
- Sun rasters - *.sr, *.ras
- TIFF files - *.tiff, *.tif
- OpenEXR Image files - *.exr
- Radiance HDR - *.hdr, *.pic
- Raster and Vector geospatial data supported by Gdal

If the image type is supported, check the path and filename are correct.